# $SCRIPT_ROOT= {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }} not working

Tags: jquery, flask

I'm following this [example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/jquery/) which uses:

```
var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
```

I've corrected to:

```
var $SCRIPT_ROOT = '{{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }}';
```

so it doesn't give the error:

> Unexpected token {

However, I am getting another error:

> GET
>   http://localhost/templates/%7B%7B%20request.script_root%7Ctojson%7Csafe%20%7D%7D/_prtpe?i=6
>   403 (Forbidden)

Any ideas why this error occurs and/or how to fix it?

---

**Edit:** this is the important piece of the Python code:

```
@app.route('/_prtpe')
def prtpe():
    i = request.args.get('i', 0, type=int)
    for position, item in enumerate(price):
        if item > i:
            return jsonify(result=percentage[position-1])

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('study3.html')
```

**Edit 2:** I moved this code from `script.js` to `study.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};             
</script>
```

but now I get an error for the JavaScript code because I use the variable `$SCRIPT_ROOT` later on.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $SCRIPT_ROOT is not defined

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about your environment (client, server)

Comment: I'm running it on a local server. I'm using jQuery in combination with flask imported in python to extract data from a csv file. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: does that mean `tojson` isn't working? because that's what gave errors, and i saw on other discussions on stack overflow to add quotes :/

Comment: ah! so the code in the python file needs a more specified path? let me edit my post

Answer (score 1):

Based on the path in the error, you're trying to fetch the template directly.  Instead, you need to render the template because it contains Jinja syntax.  You've already made a view that renders your template, but you're not using it.  Go to the path `/`, which is handled by your `index` view and returns the rendered template.

The specific error you're getting is because JavaScript doesn't understand Jinja syntax.  You do not need to wrap the result of `tojson` in quotes.

If you split your js file with Jinja syntax out from the html template, you need to render it with Jinja as well.  Anything that has Jinja syntax is not static, it can not be linked directly.  Another way of putting it is, any file you can't link to with `url_for` needs a route to render or serve it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I first tried the tutorial. My problem was that I was opening the index.html file in my browser instead of running the python program (which actually renders the template)

Try using the files in the github repo (https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/master/examples/jqueryexample)
and executing the python program ('jqueryexample.py') by clicking it.